# apache apollo mq with .NET

Tags: .net, asynchronous, message-queue, stomp, apollo

I need to work with the queue in my ASP.NET MVC application. I looking for the fastest implementation, google a little bit, looking through some benchmark and found that for the current moment Apache Apollo  MQ is fastest solution across message queues.

Is it some client libs exist , which allow to work with Apache ApolloMQ (send and consume message) in .NET world?

---

Also, if you could provide me with the benchmarks where other solutions (not including 0MQ) demonstrate better performance, please provide me with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are no official client library for apollomq in .NET right now. But it possible to consume it with STOMP protocol library [Apache.NMS.Stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/apachenmsstomp.html)

Comment: Because Apollo implements open protocols like STOMP, OpenWire, MQTT and AMQP you can use any client that supports same.  There's no real need for an Apollo specific client library.

Comment: Maybe you could describe me shortly or provide some articles what is the differences between this protocols and what is the preferable choice for performance needs?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at any [DDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) (Data Distribution Service implementations?

Check out for example [Connext DDS](http://www.rti.com/products/dds/index.html) from RTI or [Open Splice](http://www.prismtech.com/opensplice) from PrismTech. Most DDS implementations can provide a kind of durable queues (if that is the requirement), are as fast (or faster depending on use case) than ZeroMQ. They are not traditional MQ:s but may work in similar ways provided you set up their QoS in a good way.

Some DDS implementations are available freely (with limited functionality), some provide C# implementations. More vendors [can be found here](http://portals.omg.org/dds/category/web-links/vendors).

Comment: Hm, interesting. Never heard about that stuff before. Maybe you could advice some good articles on this topic?

Comment: I have not used it in any projects myself, although I have looked into it as a possible messaging/communication framework in a recent project. It really depends on the type of problem you have. Have a look at these presentations for example:  [OpenSplice SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/Angelo.Corsaro/presentations) for more info. Well worth a look. Takes a different approach to distributed communication. Well suited for disparate networks types, ad-hoc networks and high performance. Built-in discovery means you never target specific endpoint, you focus on the data.

Answer (score 2):

See the 'examples/stomp/csharp' directory in the Apollo distribution for an example of how to get .NET talking to Apollo.  BTW, since apollo supports so clients in so many different protocols, languages, and platforms, it typically does not include the client API libs in it's distributions.